# what is the difference between T sql and and Proc sql

Tags: sas

Can someone please help me with solution?

sample1:

```
ReportMonthYear ProductItemCode ClosedDate            PriorMonthCalendarDate
20160331        1234            24Mar2016 0:00:00     20160201
```

sample2:

```
ReportMonthYear ProductItemCode OpenDate     ClosedDate  OverDraftExpiryDate
20160229        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00            28Oct2016 0:00:00
20150930        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00            28Oct2016 0:00:00
20151130        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00            28Oct2016 0:00:00
20150731        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00            28Oct2016 0:00:00
20150831        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00            28Oct2016 0:00:00
20160131        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00            28Oct2016 0:00:00
20160331        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00 24Mar2016 0:00:00  
20151231        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00            28Oct2016 0:00:00
20151031        1234        13Mar2015 0:00:00            28Oct2016 0:00:00
```

I am getting correct results when I use T-SQL but not by Proc SQL.

output required:

```
ProductItemCode ReportMonthYear  PriorMonthCalendarDate  ClosedDate               OverDraftExpiryDate  earlyclosuremonths
            1234                     20160331                  20160229                            2016-03-24 00:00:00  28Oct2016 0:00:00    7
```

code in T sql:

```
select 
cd.ProductItemCode,
cd.ReportMonthYear,
cd.PriorMonthYear,
cd.ClosedDate,
df.OverDraftExpiryDate,
datediff(m,cd.ClosedDate,OverDraftExpiryDate) EarlyClosureMonths
from
sample1 cd
inner join sample2 df
on cd.ProductItemCode = df.ProductItemCode
and cd.PriorMonthYear = df.ReportMonthYear
```

code in Proc sql;

```
proc sql;
select 
cd.ProductItemCode,
cd.ReportMonthYear,
cd.PriorMonthCalendarDate,
cd.ClosedDate,
df.OverDraftExpiryDate,
intck('month',cd.ClosedDate,df.OverDraftExpiryDate) as EarlyClosureMonths
from
sample1 cd
inner join sample2 df
on cd.ProductItemCode = df.ProductItemCode
and cd.PriorMonthCalendarDate = df.ReportMonthYear;
quit;
```

Comment: Why are you using a date interval for values that have datetime values?

Comment: HI Tom, thank u for responding. I have considered date part only.sorry I forgot to take out time part. I tried but could not get answer. Can you please tell me how to get exact result?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your "date" variables actually have datetime values instead date values. Dates are stored as the number of days since 1960 and datetimes are stored as the number of seconds instead.

If you calculate months on values that are in seconds instead of days you will get the wrong answer. Use the dtmonth interval instead.

```
intck('dtmonth',cd.ClosedDate,df.OverDraftExpiryDate) as EarlyClosureMonths
```

Or convert your datetime values to dates and use the month interval.

```
intck('month',datepart(cd.ClosedDate),datepart(df.OverDraftExpiryDate)) as EarlyClosureMonths
```